# Is there a good term or word that can encompass doctors, assistants and medical records staff?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to finish this sentence with a word or term that encompasses doctors, assistants and medical records staff, management.
Using colleagues will only represent the people who had the same positions as myself

> Possess fundamental clinical skills, interpersonal skills, and cultural sensitivity towards a diverse range of patients and colleagues alike.

Comment: "Colleague" often implies a similar rank/stature of someone in the same profession as you, but I wouldn't go so far as to say it applies only to people with the same job title as you. In this example, it seems about as specific as it needs to be, covering the general category of "people you work with" in contrast to "people you don't work with". "Coworkers" or "staff" would also fit, but feels somewhat more impersonal than "colleagues".

Comment: Is this -all- hospital staff? or only a subset? Does it include orderlies and custodial staff, does it include non-medically trained people, those who don't interact with patients at all?

Comment: 'colleagues' = 'people you work with'. Yes, more likely to imply those at the same level, but can also include depending on context, managers and people who report to you.

Comment: “Colleague” is not restrictive in the sense you imagine. For example, Cambridge has “one of a group of people who work together”. I do not post this as an answer, merely suggesting that those who wrote it first do so.

Comment: health professionals

Comment: @Lambie, is *health professionals* supposed to be better than *medical professionals*, which appears in an answer posted three hours before your comment?

Comment: @jws29 Yes, it is a broader category.

Comment: The second part of your post, the indented part, is not a sentence. Otherwise, I might use the word "medico", though it might be construed as a tad informal.

Answer (score 2):

There are some possibilities depending on what you mean.

- The word "colleague" means someone who works with you. This doesn't have to be someone who does the same job as you. If you are a software developer then a salesperson, an HR assistant, an event planner and even the CTO can reasonably be your "colleague". It wouldn't include a software developer who worked for a different company.
- If you specifically mean people who work in a hospital then "hospital staff" is a good phrase to use. "Staff" in general means people who work for an organization.
- If you specifically mean people who work in the medical field then "medical professional" is a good term, although it usually means people who actively make medical decisions, such as doctors, nurses or radiologists but not records keepers.

Comment: Although one's colleague doesn't have to do exactly the same job as oneself, the word carries an implication of a rough equality of professional status. When it is used for somebody who is not, in fact, one's peer, its impact depends on who uses it: for somebody who is of a higher status to treat those of the lower as if they were equal is gracious, but for somebody of a lower status to so treat those of the higher is presumptuous.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with the others that your definition of 'colleagues' is too restrictive.  I think it would work fine for the context you gave.

Similarly, I think something like 'staff' would work in this context.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Answers should be supported by references and arguments that support them. Although your answer is appropriate it reads as an unjustified assertion or a mere opinion. Please read the site guidelines and tour, particularly https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: If some people are touchy about professionals vs. staff, then maybe *personnel* would satisfy the nitpickers.